# DialogFragment isn't modal

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In the OnResume method of my fragmentActivity i try to:

1. Check if an internet connection is available, if not display a FragmentDialog
2. if the var storeId id is set to 0, call a new activity whose ask for the id
3. display the  activity

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() ==null){
       noConDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NET_ALERT_DIALOG);
       Log.e("jedois","pas m'afficher");
   }
   if (storeId == 0) { //si on a plus la boutique id
    //call logon activity
        Intent logonActivity = new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, LogonStoreActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(logonActivity, LOGON_STORE_REQUEST);
   }
}
```

The problem is, after execute the lines "noConDialog.show(getFra..."the dialog appear but on resume execute the other line to, the my second activity start and hide my dialog.

A dialog is modal, then the app must wait the end of the Dialog, before execute the other lines . Right?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Return from the method after calling the `dialog.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code will not terminate unless you use return command. there are two ways you can handle this

**Method 1** return after showing the diaog.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() ==null){
       noConDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NET_ALERT_DIALOG);
       Log.e("jedois","pas m'afficher");
    return;
   }
   if (storeId == 0) { //si on a plus la boutique id
    //call logon activity
        Intent logonActivity = new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, LogonStoreActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(logonActivity, LOGON_STORE_REQUEST);
   }
}
```

**Method 2** Move rest of the code into else part, so only one block could execute at a time.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() ==null){
           noConDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NET_ALERT_DIALOG);
           Log.e("jedois","pas m'afficher");
       }
    else{
       if (storeId == 0) { //si on a plus la boutique id
        //call logon activity
            Intent logonActivity = new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, LogonStoreActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(logonActivity, LOGON_STORE_REQUEST);
       }
    }
}
```